# python "return none" equivalence

Tags: go, recursion, nonetype

How to achieve same thing as the following python code in Go without for loop?

```
def test(i):
    if i == 0:
        return None
    else:
        print(i)
        return test(i - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The python function never returns a value:

```
func test(i int) {
  if i==0 {
    return
  }
  fmt.Println(i)
  test(i-1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a second return value to indicate that the function returned a valid value:

```
func test(i int) (int, bool) {
    if i == 0 {
        return 0, false
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
    return test(i - 1)
}
```

In this specific example, the return value to the top-level caller is always `0, false`. Given this, the return value is not needed.

```
func test(i int) {
    if i == 0 {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
    test(i - 1)
}
```